# Cannot create query in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 3 classes (tables) and I need a method to return all companies that can deliver where client chooses:

```
minPrice, maxPrice, Weight, Volume, receiptDate, deliveryDate
```

Every delivery company should return one vehicle(out of all suitable cheapest should be returned).

```
public class Delivery
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int AvgEarnings { get; set; }

        public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int MaxWeight { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int MaxVolume { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Price { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public Delivery Delivery { get; set; }

        public List<Reservation> Reservations{ get; set; }
}

public class Reservation
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Date{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

i tried something like this but u cannot use contains on Reservations and DateTime type and i dont know how to do it

```
var vehicles = Context.Vehicles 
            .Include(p => p.Reservations)
            .Where(p => p.maxVolume >= volume
            && p.maxWeight >= weight
            && p.Price >= minPrice
            && p.Price <= maxPrice
            && !p.Reservations.Contains(receiptDate)
            && !p.Reservations.Contains(deliveryDate)
            );
```

i know this doesnt work its just to give u idea what i am trying to do

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should splitting your query in two different operations, before get all available vehicles based on the criteria and then groups them by delivery company, then for each delivery company, it selects the cheapest available vehicle.

for example:

```
var availableVehicles = context.Vehicles
            .Include(v => v.Reservations)
            .Where(v =>
                v.MaxVolume >= volume &&
                v.MaxWeight >= weight &&
                v.Price >= minPrice &&
                v.Price <= maxPrice &&
                v.Reservations.All(r => r.Date != receiptDate && r.Date != deliveryDate))
            .ToList();

var cheapestVehicles = availableVehicles
            .GroupBy(v => v.Delivery)
            .Select(group => group.OrderBy(v => v.Price)
            .FirstOrDefault())
            .ToList();
```